# How to access parameter from Client Script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview and on rowDatabound i am creating on click on that row and 
showing modal popup. what i want is when the row is clicked , the ID for that row should be passed.

```
protected void grdOrderProduct_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btnPop, "12");
    }
}
```

How can i Get this "12" on my server control. i have put 12 as static for demo. but it will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know which row was clicked, you have to use the `Row` property of the `GridViewRowEventArgs`

```
    protected void grdOrderProduct_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
            e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btnPop, e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());

        }
    }
```

RowIndex would be passed as an argument to `btnPop`. In order to receive it `btnPop` should be implementing `IPostBackEventHandler`.

Like this:

```
public class MyControl : Button, IPostBackEventHandler
  {

    // Use the constructor to defined default label text.
    public MyControl()
    {
    }

    // Implement the RaisePostBackEvent method from the
    // IPostBackEventHandler interface. 
    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
      //You receive the row number here.
    }
  }
```

Refer [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackClientHyperlink](http://ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackClientHyperlink)

Comment: How to access this value from the Function ?

Comment: i got your point. but i want to know have i need to create this class ? and where to create ?

Comment: If you want to receive custom events, then you need to create this class. You could create this in a standard cs file anywhere in your solution. Controls like these are called custom controls or server controls.

Answer (score 2):

you also can do like this

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink
(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

Comment: A description to go with this code, as to why it works the way it does, might be beneficial.